# Ubuntu on Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: samsung, tablet

I think that is an odd question but, here we go: Is there any way to install an up-to-date version of Ubuntu on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the port of [`touch` for `Galaxy tab 2 P3110`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/p3110), it is no longer updated (since 2013).

As this is an old device, Samsung have released [seven new revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_series#Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_S2) of the Galaxy tab since this one, there is no support for it, you would have to port it your self, [using this post](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/).